# Render a table in Sinatra based on JSON object?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, sinatra

An Ajax action in Sinatra is returning a JSON object. In a view, I want to render a table based on this JSON object. It, in fact, contains the list on some items.

Of course I can render the table by using JavaScript. I would parse the JSON and, for each item in it, I would render the table rows and so forth.

Is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to directly parse the JSON into a table, I'd really recommend taking advantage of one of the many JavaScript-based table renderers. I like [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) in particular, which works with jQuery.

Take a look at the JSON renderer under the "Loading Data" section.

Answer (score 0):

In Sinatra, you don't have helpers like in Rails. There's a project called SinatraContrib, that provides some helpers functionality for you. In your case, I think that parser a JSON with javascript is the best way to achieve what you want.